# sending data into the database using ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am trying to send data from a form  into the 'mess' database table through ajax but I have no error on my console and the data is not inserted into the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

// this is the form
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <fieldset style="width:40%; margin:0 auto;">
        <label for="message" id="message" >Message</label><textarea cols="60" rows="8" id="message" name="message"
        required></textarea>

       <input type="hidden" id="" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="topic_id" name="topic_id" value="<?= $topic_id ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="user_one" name="user_one" value="<?= $user_one ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="user_two" name="user_two" value="<?= $user_two ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submitted" id="send" value="Send" />
        <span id="error"></span>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

// this is my script.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    /*post message via ajax*/
    $("#send").on("click", function(){
        var message = $.trim($("#message").val()),
            topic_id = $.trim($("#topic_id").val()),
            user_one = $.trim($("#user_one").val()),
            user_two = $.trim($("#user_two").val()),
            error = $("#error");

        if((message != "") && (topic_id != "") && (user_one != "") && (user_two != "")){
            error.text("Sending...");
            $.post("handlemessageSend.php",{message:message,topic_id:topic_id,user_one:user_one,user_two:user_two}, function(data){
                error.text(data);
                //clear the message box
                $("#message").val("");
            });
        }
    });
```

// this is my handlemessageSend.php

```
    require_once("templates/connect.inc.php");
    //post message
    if(isset($_POST['message'])){
        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);
        $topic_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['topic_id']);
        $user_one = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_one']);
        $user_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_two']);


        //insert into `mess table`
        $q = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO mess(sender, reciever, message, topic_id) VALUES ('$user_one','$user_two','$message', '$topic_id')");
        if($q){
            echo "Posted";
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you submit the form normally, i.e without AJAX? And have you looked at the network tab of your developer tools to see what's being sent to the server and back when using AJAX?

Comment: @j08691 as far as I can see actually the form is submitted without ajax because he doesn't prevent default action for the form

Comment: it is just an error, even after making the action default it still don't insert into the db.

Comment: Any errors? The word `reciever` looks like a typo to me.

Comment: reciever is a field inthe mess table.

Comment: add some error reporting  at the end of you script so you can know WHAT error occured. Also, You should make this into a prepared statement (aka not escaping). http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php